# SQL - asigning same value if value true if not assign increment 1 value

Tags: sql, db2

I have the table below where for V1 column I would like to assign same value is `ACCOUNT` value is the same if not I want to assign 1 increment value.
Something similar with excel: `=if(B2=B1,C1,C1+1)`.

```
CCR   ACCOUNT   V1    
1       100     1  
2       100  
1       101  
1       102  
2       200  
3       200  
16      200  
18      200
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which database engine?

Comment: @ Douglas Barbin - DB2

Comment: Why do you want this information?  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Also - after looking at your other question - what, in a bigger picture are you trying to do (may want to post as a separate question)?  Completely mimicking Excel usually isn't the best way to approach data.  I'm getting the feeling you've broken a task down a little too far into constituent parts

Comment: @ Clockwork-Muse - I have 2 columns with over 100.000 records each. First column represent the client code and the second the account number for that client. My relations in columns are many to many, one customer can have many accounts, 2 or more customers can have same account. Based on this I have to add a value into the third column in order to group all connected clients and all their accounts.

Comment: ...I have build the logic in excel like that: sort by account, assign same value is account is the same, use min(if) array formula that will return my smallest value in turns once for CCR and once for ACCOUNT until values return are not changing any more and this will assign me for every row that is part of a group that group number.But dealing with such a high number of rows I have to replicate this in SQL.I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, here is a more general solution (database-agnostic) since certain (albeit very popular) database dialects (e.g., MySQL, SQLite, MS Access) unfortunately do not yet carry [Window Functions](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql/) and hence do not have the `Over()` clause:

```
SELECT ccr, account,
   (SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT account FROM tableName) As t2
       WHERE t2.account <= t1.account)  As V1
FROM tableName t1
```

With output:

```
ccr account V1
1     100   1
2     100   1
1     101   2
1     102   3
2     200   4
3     200   4
16    200   4
18    200   4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ccr, account, dense_rank() over (order by account) as V1
from t
```